# Why is $u\times(v\times w)=-u\mathbin{\lrcorner} (v\wedge w)$?

Tags: proof-explanation, exterior-algebra

Consider the proof of the Triple product expansion I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Using_geometric_algebra):
$\newcommand{\imult}{\mathbin{\lrcorner}}$
$$u\times(v\times w)=-u\imult (v\wedge w)=v\wedge(u\imult w)-(u\imult v)\wedge w=(u\cdot w)v-(u\cdot v)w$$
Can someone explain the first equality? I know that the LHS equals$$*(u\wedge*(v\wedge w))$$but I don't know how to proceed further...

Comment: Can you use $a \times b = -I (a \wedge b)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Rotating_systems)?

Comment: @JMP I have only had a short introduction to Clifford algebras, so I would like to see a proof.

Comment: @JMP But if necessary I can ask that in a separate question, i.e. you are welcome to post an answer with the derivation based on that equation.

Comment: I find very few about "Contractions" in the literature. Take a look at page 68 of this reference: https://people.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/Burke_DivGradCurl.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\lrcorner}
\newcommand\grade[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\Grade[1]{\Bigl\langle#1\Bigr\rangle}
$

Refer to [*The Inner Products of Geometric Algebra*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0089-5_2) (2002) by Leo Dorst for the definition and properties of the contraction $\lcontr$. Note that there are different conventions in defining the contractions that give slight variations; see for example the Appendix of [*Compendium of Multivector Contractions*](http://arxiv.org/abs/2205.07608) (2022) by André Mandolesi.

On vectors, the contraction is just $a\lcontr b = a\cdot b$. We will make use of the identity
$$
  a\lcontr(b\wedge c) = (a\lcontr b)c - b(a\lcontr c).
$$
The contractions and exterior product are *dual* in the sense that
$$
  X\wedge Y\:I = X\lcontr(YI),\quad
  X\lcontr Y\:I = X\wedge(YI),
$$
for arbitrary multivectors $X, Y$ and pseudoscalar $I$. The geometric product takes the least precedence, i.e. you should compute other products like $\wedge$ and $\lcontr$ first.

By $*X$ I would assume you mean $XI^{-1}$ for $I$ the right-handed unit pseudoscalar, but if you're referring to the Hodge star then the equivalence between these (up to some sign differences) can be confirmed just be seeing how they act on a basis of the exterior algebra; I will not do so here. In three dimensional Euclidean space, $I^{-1} = -I$ and $I^2 = -1$. It is true that
$$
  u\times(u\times w) = u\wedge[v\wedge w\:I]\:I.
$$
Continuing with the identities from above, we see
$$
  u\wedge[v\wedge w\:I]\:I
  = u\lcontr(v\wedge w\:II)
  = -u\lcontr(v\wedge w)
  = (u\lcontr w)v - (u\lcontr v)w
  = (u\cdot w)v - (u\cdot v)w.
$$
Hence we have shown that
$$
  u\times(u\times w) = (u\cdot w)v - (u\cdot v)w.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answers (+1). As I mentioned in the comments, my knowledge of Clifford algebras is very restricted, so I need to look at your references. Right now is a bad time, but in less than a week I will have written all my exams. I hope you will still be available for questions regarding your answers. One remark (since you implicitly asked): By $*$ I meant the hodge star; I thought that $$u\times v:=*(u\wedge v)$$ is the most common definition.

Comment: @Filippo I just thought maybe your star was pseudoscalar multiplication, since in geometric algebra we usually define $X^* = XI^{-1}$. It can actually be shown that the Hodge star is realized as $*X = \widetilde XI$ where the tilde is reversal, so pseudoscalar multiplication plays the role of the Hodge star. The duality identity $X\wedge(YI) = X\mathbin\lrcorner Y\:I$ is a manifestation the Hodge star identity $X\wedge(*Y) = \langle X, Y\rangle I$ for $\langle X,Y\rangle$ the standard bilinear form on multivectors.

Comment: @Filippo I would be more than happy to answer any future questions if I am able to.

Comment: Your answer is clear and it also explains the equation$$a \times b = -I (a \wedge b)$$from the comment section :)